# Why can't I have a scrolling div in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, scrolling

I have a lightning page, that contains a lightning component, that among other things shows a list of product names.  I have the product names in a list with a div with a fixed size with scrolling turned on.  In this case, the css is the relevant file:

`.THIS.productList {
    height: 10em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    overflow: scroll;
}`

When I preview the app, or when I access it from the lightning nav menu, the scrolling region works fine.  When I look at it in Salesforce1, the region doesn't scroll.

Is there a reason for this?  I suspect I am violating a rule of mobile development that everybody else knows.  What is it?

Should this work in Salesforce1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use newly added Lightning component in the Winter '17, **ui:scrollerWrapper** that enables native scrolling in Lightning Components Salesforce1 app as well as in Lightning Desktop.

> A `ui:scrollerWrapper` creates a container that enables native
>   scrolling in Salesforce1. This component enables you to nest more than
>   one scroller inside the container. Use the class attribute to define
>   the height and width of the container.

Please find the **code** below:

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <div class="mainWrap">
        <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest">
            <ul class="testDiv">        
               <li>In the Winter ’17 release, many of your favorite features 
                   are easier to use than ever before. 
               </li>
               <li>Lightning Experience has a brand new                      
                   navigation bar and lots of critical sales,
                   service, and analytics capabilities. 
               </li>
               <li>You’ve got more options for managing customer and partner
                   communities, running your business from your phone, 
                   and keeping your data and your users secure. 
               </li>
               <li>Not to mention plentiful new
                   customization and app development features, 
                   including custom Lightning apps.
               </li>                      
               <li>Other features require direct action by an administrator 
                   before users can benefit from the new functionality.
               </li>
               <li>If a key feature is also available in Salesforce1, 
                   our mobile app, we mention that in the feature description. 
               </li>
               <li>ui:scrollerWrapper
                   Creates a container that enables native scrolling in 
                   Salesforce1.
               </li>

            </ul>
        </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Style:-**

```
.THIS .sWrapTest {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: How to achieve this in LWC?